# I can't enter passwords in Safari 11.1 on macOS 10.13 High Sierra because the last character gets removed

Tags: macos, keyboard, safari, high-sierra, password

I installed a brand new *10.13* a few days ago. I downloaded it from the App Store and I installed all updates. I'm runnning *Safari Version 11.1 (13605.1.33.1.4)*.

Somehow I managed to log into Google, but I can't log into any other website. Safari does the following **when entering text into `password` fields**  – on every other webpage except for Google:

- the first character is entered
- after that, it looks like the last character is removed after keyup
- this happens when using the internal or an external keyboard

*Normal* fields like `text`, `textarea` etc. work fine, though.

Here's a gif showing the problem – no <kbd>Backspace</kbd> or <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Del</kbd> is pressed. This happens just in Safari  – Chrome and Firefox work fine:

[image]

---

I have the following settings:

- autofill: don't store passwords and credit card information
- no extensions are installed
- Adobe Acrobat plug-in is installed

I tried to change the settings and to disable the Arcobat plug-in, but nothing changed.

---

It seems that macOS’ autocorrection kicks in. I noticed this behavior in a password-field that could be switched to plaintext: Characters get replaced with emojis. For example:

```
()
```

… was turned into:

```
☮
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I got the answer to this annoying problem. I had a configuration in System Preferences / Keyboard / Text to replace 3 big dots ••• with this character: ∴ 
So every time I typed passwords in Safari, the last 3 characters of the password were replaced with this one ∴ but represented as another big dot since it's a password field. I deleted the substitution configuration and the problem was solved.

[image: System Preferences / Keyboard / Text]

Comment: Ooooh boy, thank you - that solved it. :D

Answer (score 1):

I assumed you checked your accessibility and keyboard preferences. I have had numerous issues with keyboard setting being modified/added during the updates. sticky keys and other settings were modified that I wasn't aware of...I had to start using the manual keyboard viewer until I was able to get it fixed...

[image: Valid XHTML].

only other thingi I can think of is trying on an alternate or guest login to see if you have the same problem on a clean user.

I know I am still struggling with my fare share of HSierra simple glitches but I hope you can get this one solved! Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried erasing history from all time and also going to

Safari > system preferences > security > erase all website data

Let the website data screen load a second or two it can delay on bringing up the list. Deleting this will NOT delete any personal or saved information.

Then hold Command+Option+Esc click “force quit” safari.

I would then shut down my computer restart it and see if that works.[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. Unfortunately, this didn't do the trick. The problem is still there.